# Programmatically Displaying a UILabel from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm re-factoring my code and would like to move a whole bunch of UILabels into another class to tidy things up a bit.  I'm missing one puzzle piece to be able to do so though (or maybe I'm just tired lol)  Anyway here's the simplified code showing my issue.  Thanks in advance to anyone who helps :)

```
@interface MyClass : UIView {
    UILabel *classLabel;
}
@property (assign) UILabel *classLabel;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize classLabel;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    }
return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {[super dealloc];}
@end

@interface LabelTestViewController : UIViewController {
    MyClass *myClassInstance;
    UILabel *myLabel;
}
@property (assign) UILabel *myLabel;
@end

@implementation LabelTestViewController
@synthesize myLabel;
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   // this shows a label on the screen as expected 
    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 20)];
    myLabel.text = @"Hello";
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];

    // this doesn't show anything on the scree
    myClassInstance = [MyClass new];
    [myClassInstance drawRect:CGRectMake(10, 50, 50, 20)];   // I suspect I need to call a different method, just don't know which one.  initWithFrame is what I used at the time of creation of the label in the previous working scenario.  is there an equivalent?
    myClassInstance.classLabel.text = @"Goodbye";
    [self.view addSubview:myClassInstance.classLabel];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];}
- (void)viewDidUnload {}
- (void)dealloc {[super dealloc];}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1)  You should never call drawRect directly.  Instead, call setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect.  See the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) or the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) for more info.

2)  But that may not be source of your problem.  From your code, it is difficult to tell what ends up in classLabel after you are done setting it up, but I expect it's not what you need.  In particular, it needs a frame.  I would suggest setting a CGRect variable to myClassLabel.frame and seeing what you end up with.

Comment: On point 2 I don't do anything to set up the label in MyClass except declare its existence.  I'm really only putting the label in there because in my real code it's the logical place for it and it makes my main code way way less bloated (There are heaps of class instances related to specific labels).  
If I want to add myClassInstance.classLabel to self.view I don't have to first add the MyClass view to the self.view do I?  I'll try your CGRect variable suggestion.

I'm aware of point 1 too, I was just grasping at straws at that point :)

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: omg lol how embarrasing  all I needed to was put in a myClassInstance.classLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 18)]; once I had the myClassInstance already declared